# Making large amount of Gravy

Tags: flavor, thickening, roux, gravy

When making larger amounts of gravy do you have to increase the amount of roux I usually use 4 TBSP of fat and 4 TBSP of flour but wondering if making larger amount of gravy like maybe 8 cups would you increase amount of roux?

Comment: Ate you serving all that gravy in one meal, or are you just pre-cooking many servings?

Answer (score 3):

I would assume yes.

you use 4tbsp flour and fat for what amount of liquid ?

if you double the liquid, you should double the roux.

If there's not enough roux, then your gravy will be too "liquid".

for reference this recipe : 
http://www.chef-menus.com/large_quantity_recipes_gravy.html